# Отображение товара без id - bitrix

Tags: битрикс

коллеги. Столкнулся с проблемой... Готовое решение на битрикс не выводит "ID" товара, когда на него нажимаешь (страница с товаром). Нужно, чтобы у каждого товара был id, который бы отображался для всех пользователей. Какие настройки необходимо изменить? Спасибо.

```html
   <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:news", 
"catalog", 
array(
 "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "aspro_scorp_catalog",
 "IBLOCK_ID" => "95",
 "NEWS_COUNT" => "6",
 "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
 "USE_RSS" => "N",
 "USE_RATING" => "N",
 "USE_CATEGORIES" => "Y",
 "USE_FILTER" => "N",
 "SORT_BY1" => "SORT",
 "SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
 "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
 "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
 "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
 "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
 "SEF_FOLDER" => "/catalog/",
 "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
 "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
 "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
 "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
 "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
 "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
 "CACHE_GROUPS" => "N",
 "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
 "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
 "SHOW_404" => "Y",
 "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
 "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
 "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
 "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
 "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
 "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array(
  0 => "ID",
  1 => "CODE",
  2 => "NAME",
  3 => "PREVIEW_TEXT",
  4 => "PREVIEW_PICTURE",
  5 => "DETAIL_TEXT",
  6 => "DETAIL_PICTURE",
  7 => "",
 ),
 "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
  0 => "FORM_ORDER",
  1 => "PRICE",
  2 => "PRICEOLD",
  3 => "STATUS",
  4 => "ARTICLE",
  5 => "soput_tovary",
  6 => "",
 ),
 "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
 "SORT_PROP" => array(
  0 => "sort",
  1 => "ARTICLE",
  2 => "soput_tovary",
 ),
 "SORT_PROP_DEFAULT" => "sort",
 "SORT_DIRECTION" => "asc",
 "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
 "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
 "META_DESCRIPTION" => "FORM_ORDER",
 "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
 "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
 "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array(
  0 => "ID",
  1 => "NAME",
  2 => "PREVIEW_TEXT",
  3 => "PREVIEW_PICTURE",
  4 => "DETAIL_TEXT",
  5 => "DETAIL_PICTURE",
  6 => "",
 ),
 "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
  0 => "FORM_QUESTION",
  1 => "FORM_ORDER",
  2 => "PRICE",
  3 => "PRICEOLD",
  4 => "STATUS",
  5 => "ARTICLE",
  6 => "BRAND",
  7 => "TYPE",
  8 => "COLOR",
  9 => "SIZE",
  10 => "LINK_PROJECTS",
  11 => "soput_tovary",
  12 => "DOCUMENTS",
  13 => "",
 ),
 "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "Y",
 "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
 "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
 "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
 "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
 "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
 "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
 "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
 "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
 "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "Y",
 "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
 "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
 "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
 "VIEW_TYPE" => "table",
 "SHOW_IMAGE" => "Y",
 "SHOW_NAME" => "Y",
 "SHOW_DETAIL" => "Y",
 "IMAGE_POSITION" => "left",
 "COUNT_IN_LINE" => "3",
 "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
 "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
 "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "Y",
 "SHOW_DETAIL_LINK" => "Y",
 "USE_SHARE" => "N",
 "S_ASK_QUESTION" => "",
 "S_ORDER_PRODUCT" => "",
 "T_GALLERY" => "",
 "T_DOCS" => "",
 "T_PROJECTS" => "",
 "T_CHARACTERISTICS" => "",
 "FILTER_URL_TEMPLATE" => "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/filter/#SMART_FILTER_PATH#/apply/",
 "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "Y",
 "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "catalog",
 "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
 "SET_BREADCRUMBS_CHAIN_FROM" => "NAME",
 "T_VIDEO" => "",
 "COMPOSITE_FRAME_MODE" => "A",
 "COMPOSITE_FRAME_TYPE" => "AUTO",
 "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
 "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "Y",
 "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
 "FILE_404" => "",
 "S_ORDER_STUDY" => "",
 "T_STOCK" => "",
 "T_GOODS" => "",
 "T_SERVICES" => "",
 "T_REVIEWS" => "",
 "T_STAFF" => "",
 "IMAGE_CATALOG_POSITION" => "left",
 "SHOW_TABS" => "Y",
 "SHOW_SECTION_PREVIEW_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
 "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
 "SHARE_HIDE" => "N",
 "SHARE_TEMPLATE" => "",
 "SHARE_HANDLERS" => array(
  0 => "mailru",
  1 => "twitter",
  2 => "facebook",
  3 => "vk",
  4 => "delicious",
  5 => "lj",
 ),
 "SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN" => "",
 "SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_KEY" => "",
 "CATEGORY_IBLOCK" => array(
  0 => "95",
  1 => "103",
  2 => "107",
 ),
 "CATEGORY_CODE" => "CATEGORY",
 "CATEGORY_ITEMS_COUNT" => "5",
 "CATEGORY_THEME_95" => "photo",
 "CATEGORY_THEME_103" => "list",
 "CATEGORY_THEME_107" => "photo",
 "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
  "news" => "http://xn-----blcb5al9aegmgbigb2l.xn--p1ai/catalog/",
  "section" => "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/",
  "detail" => "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
 )
),
false
);?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так это вы кинули компонент новостей, а не catalog.element

Comment: @k0mar извиняюсь) Насколько я понял, это код который нужен. Исправил.

Comment: всё еще актуально... и еще, может быть кто-либо сталкивался с проблемой. Когда делаешь заказ на сайте, приходит оповещение на емейл о том, что сделан заказ такой-то вещи с таким то АЙДИ. Проблема в том, что на сайте нет поиска по ИД и он нигде не показывается обычному пользователю (и не обычному, а виден только из панели). А в сообщении, которое приходит на емейл, нет даже названия этого предмета, а есть только ИД......

Comment: а что мешает вывести ид товара доработав код шаблона?

Comment: @NikolajSarry непонимание, в каком файле (файлах) я это должен отредактировать? Знаний не то что бы нет, просто по битриксу не особо понимаю....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если включить режим ермитажа и навестись на товар то у вас появиться рамка над товаром и там будет шестеренка а справа от нее стрелочка вниз там будет редактирование шаблона нашимаете и в всплывающем окне буте вверху путь к файлу шаблона

и в нужное место вставить

`<?=$arResult["ID"]?>`

Но выводить ИД товара плохо, так как можно узнать размер каталога и конкуренты могут этим воспользоваться, лучше изменить письмо и добавить название